# Extract some value from complex json field type in Postgresql

Tags: json, stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgresql-12

I have postgres table (let say *my_table*) containing JSON field (let say *json_field*) as:

```
(1, {"data": [{"val_a":1, "b":"somevalue"}, {"val_a":2, "b":"othervalue"}, ...]}),  
(2, {"data": [{"val_a":22, "b":"somevalue2"}, {"val_a":12, "b":"othervalue2"}, ...]}),  
....  
(n, {"data": [{"val_a":11, "b":"somevaluen"}, {"val_a":122, "b":"othervaluen"}, ...]})
```

I want to return ARRAY - int[] of *val_a* values only.

I tried stored procedure (plpgsql), as follows:

```
declare
    data_array json[];
    vals float8[];
begin
    SELECT json_field->'data' into data_array FROM my_table;
    FOREACH i IN ARRAY data_array
        vals := array_append(vals, i->'val_a')
        -- nor array_append(vals, i->'val_a') works
    END LOOP;
    return vals;
end;
```

which gives me syntax error:
array_append(vals, i->'val_a').

What is the best way to extract *val_a*?

Using PostgreSQL 12.6

Comment: Don't abuse JSON like this. Store these data in a separate table without JSON columns and have a foreign key relationship between the tables. Then the exercise becomes trivial.

Comment: Thank @LaurenzAlbe, unfortunetely can not do thak - I'm working on existing database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a JSONPATH expression:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query_array(json_field, '$.data[*].val_a') FROM my_table;

 jsonb_path_query_array 
------------------------
 [1, 2]
(1 row)
```

This is available from PostgreSQL v12 on.